# Как убрать линию между словами в списке?

Tags: html, css

```css
header {
  height: 70px;
}

.nav_header {
  padding: 0;
}

.nav_header ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.nav_header ul li .item__text {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

.nav_header ul li .item__text:hover {
  color: #00cdff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}

.nav_header ul li .item__text:not(:hover) {
  color: whitesmoke;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.nav_header ul li .item__text::after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #00cdff;
  transition: 0.5s;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.nav_header ul li .item__text:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.nav_header ul li .item__text:active {
  transform: scale(0.97);
}
```

```html
<header class="row sticky-top">
  <div class="col-xl-6 nav_header my-auto">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="item__text" href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a class="item__text" href="#">Cabinet</a></li>
        <li><a class="item__text" href="#">Packages</a></li>
        <li><a class="item__text" href="#">Balance</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

`
```

Почему при выделение слов в списке, выделяется какая-то вертикальная линия между словами?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это убрать?

Comment: Точный ответ зависит от вёрстки этого места

Comment: Чем Вам оно мешает? Эти элементы должны быть кликабельны, а не виделяемы.  Вы пытаетесь сделать что бы красиво выделялись элементы которые никто не должен выделять, вместо того, что бы подумать о том как запретить выделение этих элементов. Как по мне, то это уже отачивание до безупречности сайта. А таким занимаются когда есть код верстки под рукой и уже есть понимание где возможно зарылся баг.  В вопросе Вы кода не приводите. Как Вам смогут помочь?

Comment: мне одному это похоже на простое выделение мышкой?

Comment: @GGO ,это заметно даже не при выделении, когда мишку навести на эту  область, то курсор меняется, проблема не большая, но хочется все таки убрать это.

Comment: `user-select: none;`

Comment: Просто удали из css = .nav_header ul li .item__text::after

Answer (score 1):

Это отступ примерно в 4px - *проблема* `inline-block` элементов.

Чтобы их убрать нужно убрать фактические отступы между элементами чтобы удалить пробел, или измените размер шрифта родителя на 0, а затем при необходимости сбросьте размер шрифта в дочерних элементах.

```css
header {
  height: 70px;
}

.nav_header {
  padding: 0;
}

.nav_header ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.nav_header ul li .item__text {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

.nav_header ul li .item__text:hover {
  color: #00cdff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}

.nav_header ul li .item__text:not(:hover) {
  color: whitesmoke;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.nav_header ul li .item__text::after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #00cdff;
  transition: 0.5s;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.nav_header ul li .item__text:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.nav_header ul li .item__text:active {
  transform: scale(0.97);
}
```

```html
<header class="row sticky-top">
  <div class="col-xl-6 nav_header my-auto">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="item__text" href="#">About</a></li><li><a class="item__text" href="#">Cabinet</a></li><li><a class="item__text" href="#">Packages</a></li><li><a class="item__text" href="#">Balance</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

`
```

Еще один вариант решения данной проблемы - это задать родительскому элементу `display: flex` , тогда внутренние элементы будут обладать свойствами блочного элемента.

```css
header {
  height: 70px;
}

.nav_header {
  padding: 0;
  
  display: flex;
}

.nav_header ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.nav_header ul li .item__text {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

.nav_header ul li .item__text:hover {
  color: #00cdff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}

.nav_header ul li .item__text:not(:hover) {
  color: whitesmoke;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.nav_header ul li .item__text::after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #00cdff;
  transition: 0.5s;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.nav_header ul li .item__text:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.nav_header ul li .item__text:active {
  transform: scale(0.97);
}
```

```html
<header class="row sticky-top">
  <div class="col-xl-6 nav_header my-auto">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="item__text" href="#">About</a></li><li><a class="item__text" href="#">Cabinet</a></li><li><a class="item__text" href="#">Packages</a></li><li><a class="item__text" href="#">Balance</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

`
```

Answer (score 0):

Это виртуальный разделитель, вы его не уберете. По-сути он наследует поведение мышки от родителя - контейнера с пунктами меню.
Чтобы избавиться от эффекта на скрине, запретите выделение мышкой и все

Comment: Спасибо, я понял)

Answer (score 0):

Есть еще один вариант, но без использования тегов списка.

```html
<ul>
          <li><a class="item__text" href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a class="item__text" href="#">Cabinet</a></li>
          <li><a class="item__text" href="#">Packages</a></li>
          <li><a class="item__text" href="#">Balance</a></li>
        </ul>
```

можно назначить этот (список) с помощью Flexbox:

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Comment: везде где у вас ul li заменяйте на тег p (у меня исчез разделитель)